# Include accolade in bipartite graph to group nodes together

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to include accolades in my bipartite graph to show that nodes belong to a certain group. With the code below I created the following bipartite graph:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
  every node/.style={draw,circle},
  fsnode/.style={fill=myblue},
  ssnode/.style={fill=mygreen},
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=-2pt,text width=2cm},
  ->,shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
]
% the vertices of P
\begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=10mm]
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f1) [label=left: $p_{1}$] {};
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f2) [label=left: $p_{2}$] {};
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f3) [label=left: ] {};
  \node[fsnode,on chain] (f4) [label=left: $p_{n}$] {};
\end{scope}

% the vertices of L
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=0cm,start chain=going below,node distance=10mm]
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s1) [label=right: $l_{1}$] {};
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s2) [label=right: $l_{2}$] {};
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s3) [label=right: ] {};
  \node[ssnode,on chain] (s4) [label=right: $l_{m}$] {};
\end{scope}

% the set P
\node [myblue,fit=(f1) (f4),label=above:$Products$] {};
% the set L
\node [mygreen,fit=(s1) (s4),label=above:$Locations$] {};
% the edges
\draw[ultra thin,dashed,-] (f2) -- (f3);
\draw[ultra thin,dashed,-] (f3) -- (f4);
\draw[ultra thin,dashed,-] (s2) -- (s3);
\draw[ultra thin,dashed,-] (s3) -- (s4);
\draw[-,dotted] (f1) -- (s1);
\draw[-,dotted] (f1) -- (s2);
\draw[-,dotted] (f1) -- (s3);
\draw[-,dotted] (f1) -- (s4);
\draw[-,dotted] (f2) -- (s1);
\draw[-,dotted] (f2) -- (s2);
\draw[-,dotted] (f2) -- (s3);
\draw[-,dotted] (f2) -- (s4);
\draw[-,dotted] (f3) -- (s1);
\draw[-,dotted] (f3) -- (s2);
\draw[-,dotted] (f3) -- (s3);
\draw[-,dotted] (f3) -- (s4);
\draw[-,dotted] (f4) -- (s1);
\draw[-,dotted] (f4) -- (s2);
\draw[-,dotted] (f4) -- (s3);
\draw[-,dotted] (f4) -- (s4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

This induces the image:
[image]

But what I would like is the following image:
[image]

What code do I have to add to make use of accolades or something simular?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `brace` decoration from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library for that. <s>I used *a lot* of `shift`s to make it a bit better looking, but you can choose to omit those.</s> By using the method as explained by [@marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446104/include-accolade-in-bipartite-graph-to-group-nodes-together/446107?noredirect=1#comment1120406_446107), all the `shift`s can be omitted.

This is the code for the braces:

```
    \node[fit={(f1)(f3)(f3-|set1.west)},subset] (c1-fit) {};
    \node[fit={(f4)(f5)(f5-|set1.west)},subset] (c2-fit) {};
    \node[fit={(f7)(f8)(f8-|set1.west)},subset] (c3-fit) {};
    \node[fit={(s1)(s2)(s2-|set2.east)},subset] (lc1-fit) {};
    \node[fit={(s3)(s5)(s5-|set2.east)},subset] (lc2-fit) {};
    \node[fit={(s8)(s8)(s8-|set2.east)},subset,inner ysep=10pt] (lc3-fit) {};

    \begin{scope}[decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}]
        \begin{scope}[decoration={mirror},every node/.style={midway,left,xshift=-3mm}]
            \draw[decorate] (c1-fit.north west) -- (c1-fit.south west) node(C1){$ C_1 $};
            \draw[decorate] (c2-fit.north west) -- (c2-fit.south west) node(C2){$ C_2 $};
            \draw[decorate] (c3-fit.north west) -- (c3-fit.south west) node(Cg){$ C_\gamma $};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway,right,xshift=3mm}]
            \draw[decorate] (lc1-fit.north east) -- (lc1-fit.south east) node(LC1){$ L^{C_1} $};
            \draw[decorate] (lc2-fit.north east) -- (lc2-fit.south east) node(LC2){$ L^{C_2} $};
            \draw[decorate] (lc3-fit.north east) -- (lc3-fit.south east) node(LCg){$ L^{C_\gamma} $};
        \end{scope}
    \end{scope}
```

[image]

I also used some `\foreach` loops to ease the drawing of all those similar lines, and to place the circular nodes that don't have a label.

Also I noticed that you set `->` for the entire `tikzpicture`, and then continue to set the `-` key for all `\draw` commands, which feels a bit counterproductive so I removed that. Additionally I changed the `every node/.style` to a `base node/.style` and used the inheritance of styles to make sure that both the `fsnode` style and the `ssnode` style inherit its properties. Finally I changed the font of the two top labels (*Products* and *Locations*) to `\itshape`, instead of typesetting those words in mathmode, because it simply looks better.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
        base node/.style={draw,circle},
        fsnode/.style={base node,fill=myblue},
        ssnode/.style={base node,fill=mygreen},
        set/.style={ellipse,draw,inner xsep = 20pt,inner ysep=-20pt},
        subset/.style={inner sep=3pt},
        shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
    ]
        % the vertices of P
        \begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=10mm]
            \node[fsnode,on chain] (f1) [label=left: $p_{1}$] {};
            \node[fsnode,on chain] (f2) [label=left: $p_{2}$] {};
            \foreach \i in {3,...,7}{
                \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) {};
            }
            \node[fsnode,on chain] (f8) [label=left: $p_{n}$] {};
        \end{scope}

        % the vertices of L
        \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=0cm,start chain=going below,node distance=10mm]
            \node[ssnode,on chain] (s1) [label=right: $l_{1}$] {};
            \node[ssnode,on chain] (s2) [label=right: $l_{2}$] {};
            \foreach \i in {3,...,7}{
                \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) {};
            }
            \node[ssnode,on chain] (s8) [label=right: $l_{m}$] {};
        \end{scope}

        % the set P
        \node [set,myblue,fit=(f1) (f8),label={[font=\itshape]above:Products}] (set1) {};
        % the set L
        \node [set,mygreen,fit=(s1) (s8),label={[font=\itshape]above:Locations}] (set2) {};
        % the edges
        \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,8}{
            \draw[thin,dashed] (f\j) -- (f\i);
            \draw[thin,dashed] (s\j) -- (s\i);
        }
        \foreach \i in {1,...,8}{
            \foreach \j in {1,...,8}{
                \draw[dotted] (f\i) -- (s\j);
            }
        }

        \node[fit={(f1)(f3)(f3-|set1.west)},subset] (c1-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(f4)(f5)(f5-|set1.west)},subset] (c2-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(f7)(f8)(f8-|set1.west)},subset] (c3-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(s1)(s2)(s2-|set2.east)},subset] (lc1-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(s3)(s5)(s5-|set2.east)},subset] (lc2-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(s8)(s8)(s8-|set2.east)},subset,inner ysep=10pt] (lc3-fit) {};

        \begin{scope}[decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}]
            \begin{scope}[decoration={mirror},every node/.style={midway,left,xshift=-3mm}]
                \draw[decorate] (c1-fit.north west) -- (c1-fit.south west) node (C1) {$ C_1 $};
                \draw[decorate] (c2-fit.north west) -- (c2-fit.south west) node (C2) {$ C_2 $};
                \draw[decorate] (c3-fit.north west) -- (c3-fit.south west) node (Cg) {$ C_\gamma $};
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway,right,xshift=3mm}]
                \draw[decorate] (lc1-fit.north east) -- (lc1-fit.south east) node (LC1) {$ L^{C_1} $};
                \draw[decorate] (lc2-fit.north east) -- (lc2-fit.south east) node (LC2) {$ L^{C_2} $};
                \draw[decorate] (lc3-fit.north east) -- (lc3-fit.south east) node (LCg) {$ L^{C_\gamma} $};
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

        \draw[thin,dashed] (C2) -- (Cg);
        \draw[thin,dashed] (LC2) -- (LCg);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**PS:** I really like the `chain`s! Perfect for this application.

**Edit** ([@Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446104/include-accolade-in-bipartite-graph-to-group-nodes-together/446107?noredirect=1#comment1120308_446107))
One might argue that having the labels of the sets in upright shape is aesthetically more acceptable. I will leave the choice for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,fit,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
%    \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
        base node/.style={draw,circle},
        fsnode/.style={base node,fill=myblue},
        ssnode/.style={base node,fill=mygreen},
        set/.style={ellipse,draw,inner xsep = 20pt,inner ysep=-20pt},
        subset/.style={inner sep=3pt},
        shorten >= 3pt,shorten <= 3pt
    ]
        % the vertices of P
        \begin{scope}[start chain=going below,node distance=10mm]
            \node[fsnode,on chain] (f1) [label=left: $p_{1}$] {};
            \node[fsnode,on chain] (f2) [label=left: $p_{2}$] {};
            \foreach \i in {3,...,7}{
                \node[fsnode,on chain] (f\i) {};
            }
            \node[fsnode,on chain] (f8) [label=left: $p_{n}$] {};
        \end{scope}

        % the vertices of L
        \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm,yshift=0cm,start chain=going below,node distance=10mm]
            \node[ssnode,on chain] (s1) [label=right: $l_{1}$] {};
            \node[ssnode,on chain] (s2) [label=right: $l_{2}$] {};
            \foreach \i in {3,...,7}{
                \node[ssnode,on chain] (s\i) {};
            }
            \node[ssnode,on chain] (s8) [label=right: $l_{m}$] {};
        \end{scope}

        % the set P
        \node [set,myblue,fit=(f1) (f8),label=above:Products] (set1) {};
        % the set L
        \node [set,mygreen,fit=(s1) (s8),label=above:Locations] (set2) {};
        % the edges
        \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,8}{
            \draw[thin,dashed] (f\j) -- (f\i);
            \draw[thin,dashed] (s\j) -- (s\i);
        }
        \foreach \i in {1,...,8}{
            \foreach \j in {1,...,8}{
                \draw[dotted] (f\i) -- (s\j);
            }
        }

        \node[fit={(f1)(f3)(f3-|set1.west)},subset] (c1-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(f4)(f5)(f5-|set1.west)},subset] (c2-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(f7)(f8)(f8-|set1.west)},subset] (c3-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(s1)(s2)(s2-|set2.east)},subset] (lc1-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(s3)(s5)(s5-|set2.east)},subset] (lc2-fit) {};
        \node[fit={(s8)(s8)(s8-|set2.east)},subset,inner ysep=10pt] (lc3-fit) {};

        \begin{scope}[decoration={brace,amplitude=3mm}]
            \begin{scope}[decoration={mirror},every node/.style={midway,left,xshift=-3mm}]
                \draw[decorate] (c1-fit.north west) -- (c1-fit.south west) node (C1) {$ C_1 $};
                \draw[decorate] (c2-fit.north west) -- (c2-fit.south west) node (C2) {$ C_2 $};
                \draw[decorate] (c3-fit.north west) -- (c3-fit.south west) node (Cg) {$ C_\gamma $};
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={midway,right,xshift=3mm}]
                \draw[decorate] (lc1-fit.north east) -- (lc1-fit.south east) node (LC1) {$ L^{C_1} $};
                \draw[decorate] (lc2-fit.north east) -- (lc2-fit.south east) node (LC2) {$ L^{C_2} $};
                \draw[decorate] (lc3-fit.north east) -- (lc3-fit.south east) node (LCg) {$ L^{C_\gamma} $};
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

        \draw[thin,dashed] (C2) -- (Cg);
        \draw[thin,dashed] (LC2) -- (LCg);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Upvoted. Can I ask a favour, please? Can you edit your answer, putting the text in roman and not italic? It is better, for my opinion.

Comment: @Sebastiano Do you mean the top labels in (normal) upright shape?

Comment: Products and Locations,  Max, normal shape exact.

Comment: But you are not that you had to let everyone know :-):-). Aesthetically now it is more beautiful :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano I actually wanted to emphasize that *if* you want italic text *then* `\itshape` is better looking than `$ ... $` *endif*. By making the labels upright I will not make that point clear.

Comment: +1, very nice! You could actually use fit also to determine the size of the braces. That is, you could fit the nodes that you want to embrace and also one coordinate on the border `fit=(f1) (f3) (f1 -| Fit1)`, where `Fit1` is the blue fit node, and then draw the brace from the fit box south west to north west, say.

Comment: @marmot That's really clever!

Comment: @Max Thank you! Really elegant and clever way of coding such a bipartite graph. The braces work perfect!